# Is there a memory heap differ for Javascript - like JVisualVM is for Java?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks

When hunting down memory leaks, it is vital to be able to compare the heap state before and after some actions (to make sure that objects are not leaked). When debugging this kind of thing under Java, JVisualVM was immensely helpful, because it could take snapshots of heap usage at the press of a button, and then compare them and show what additional objects appeared in the interim.

Is there such a memory heap differ for JavaScript? I am developing a complex Single Page Application with AngularJS, and need to trace down apparent memory leaks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you hear about Chrome devtools?
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling

Comment: Also a link to more specific documentation within the same Dev Tools Docs on JavaScript memory leaks: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling - The Profiling tool is brilliant if you know where to look through the elaborative information =)